# How to fetch radio button value dynamically in angular 2?

Tags: angular

Need to display radio button values dynamically from array, and fetch the value of it based on which I need to display a `<div>`. please find the code below

html

```
<div *ngFor = "let fruit of fruits"
<input type = "radio"/>{{fruit}}>
</div>
```

component.ts -> contains the following array

```
fruits : string[] = ["apple", "mango"];
```

With this I am getting the radio buttons apple and mango.Need to get the value of the selected radio button (in assigning[(ngModel)], value) and Need to display another div based on individual selections.
Please guide me on this

Answer (score 2):

You can use **`[value]`**

```
<div *ngFor="let fruit of fruits">
    <input type="radio" formControlName="options" [value]="fruit">
    {{fruit}}
</div>`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div *ngFor="let fruit of fruits">
<input type="radio" [value]="fruit" 
(change)="selectedFruitValue(fruit)">
{{fruit}}
</div>

in your ts file
first define a variable
i.e
fruitValue:string
```

and then write a function

```
selectedFruitValue(fruit){

this.fruitValue = fruit;

//for checking purpose
 console.log('fruit value is':+this.fruitValue);
```

}